# Do we have public APIs for 3d touch in iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

How can I build custom quick links on 3d touch just like native apps in iPhone 6s and 6s Plus?

Comment: Take a look here https://developer.apple.com/ios/3d-touch/

Comment: You can find info about 3D-Touch API [here](https://developer.apple.com/ios/3d-touch/), it's available in last GM version of SDK.

Comment: 3D Touch API is available on Xcode 7.1 beta i think

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple as expected:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
     guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
     if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
        println("Pressure is \(touch.force) and maximum force is \(touch.maximumPossibleForce)")
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I referred from [**realm.io**](https://web.archive.org/web/20170331182736/https://realm.io/news/tips-for-ios-9-development/)

In fundamental level, exposed simply as a new property in UITouch

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
     guard let touch = touches.first else { return }
     if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
        println("Touch pressure is \(touch.force), maximum possible force is \(touch.maximumPossibleForce)")
     } }
```

In addition to the UITouch APIs, Apple has also provided two new sets of classes adding 3D Touch functionality to apps: UIPreviewAction and UIApplicationShortcutItem.

UIPreviewAction allows developers to quickly present content in a new ‘preview’ overlay when you 3D Touch a UI element. This is a fantastic way to allow a quick glance at app-specific content, such as email messages, photos, or even websites without needing to commit to a full view controller transition.

UIApplicationShortcutItem objects enable an amazing new feature right on the iOS Home screen. When users 3D Touch an app icon, a sheet of options is presented, allowing the user to quickly jump to a specific section of the app, or perform an in-app action.

Also, don't forget [apple document for 3D touch](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/user-interaction/3d-touch/).

Comment: I have a 6s, when I tried this I got "Pressure is 0.0 and maximum force is 6.66666666666667" - the pressure is 0.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are close, but no cigar. You need to add the `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method (not `touchesBegan:withEvent:`):

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let touch = touches.first else {
        return
    }

    if traitCollection.forceTouchCapability == .Available {
        print("Touch pressure is \(touch.force), maximum possible force is \(touch.maximumPossibleForce)")
    }
}
```