# iOS 3D Touch in Objective C

Tags: ios

Any one have any idea how can we implement `3d touch` feature in `objective C`? I already check the app documentation but no example is related to objective C code.

Any sample code or example, how to implement ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: the `UITouch` gives you the information about the force of a touch via the `force` property (iOS9+), and you can grab the current `UITouch` event via any `UIResponser` class (iOS2+); the rest or how you can use this are limited by your imagination only.

Comment: If someone needs the answer for Swift, check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/32593044/4106559

Answer (score 3):

The way I am doing this is to use a [DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer](https://github.com/foggzilla/DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer) that I have made available. This is a gesture recognizer extension that detects force touch and works alongside other gesture recognizers.

The `DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer` provides continuous updates about the pressure changes so you can do nice things like augment the view as the user varies their pressure on it, as opposed to just triggering a single event. If you just want a single event you can ignore eveything in the `DFContinuousForceTouchDelegate` except the `- (void) forceTouchRecognized` callback.

https://github.com/foggzilla/DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer

You can download this and run the sample app on a device that supports force press to see how it feels.

In your UIViewController implement:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    _forceTouchRecognizer = [[DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
    _forceTouchRecognizer.forceTouchDelegate = self;

    [self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:_forceTouchRecognizer];
}
```

implement the delegate protocol for force touch:

```
#pragma DFContinuousForceTouchDelegate

- (void) forceTouchRecognized:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Force Touch" message:@"YEAH!!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    });
}
- (void) forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer didStartWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce {
    CGFloat transformDelta = 1.0f + ((force/maxForce) / 3.0f);
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(transformDelta, transformDelta);
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer didMoveWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce {
    CGFloat transformDelta = 1.0f + ((force/maxForce) / 3.0f);
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(transformDelta, transformDelta);
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer didCancelWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce  {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) forceTouchRecognizer:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer didEndWithForce:(CGFloat)force maxForce:(CGFloat)maxForce  {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void) forceTouchDidTimeout:(DFContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    [self.imageView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Note that this will only be useful on a device that supports force touch.

Also you should not add the UIContinuousForceTouchGestureRecognizer to a view if are you running on iOS8 or under since it uses the new `force` property on `UITouch` only available in iOS9.

If you add this on iOS8 it will crash, so conditionally add this recognizer based on what iOS version you are running on if you are supporting versions older than iOS9.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example adapted from yeungkaho's example on github

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self handleTouches:touches];
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self handleTouches:touches];
}
-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self setForcePercentage:0];
}
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self setForcePercentage:0];
}
-(void)handleTouches:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGFloat force = touch.force;
        CGFloat percentage = force/touch.maximumPossibleForce;
        [self setForcePercentage:percentage];
        break;
    }
}

-(void)setForcePercentage:(CGFloat)percentage{

    NSLog(@"LEVEL = %f",percentage*100);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I am sharing the source code for pressing on app icon populate 4 item in list**

**Step 1**:- Import class in appDelegate.m

import sys/utsname.h

**Step 2**:-

```
#pragma MARK for Get Machine Name

-  (NSString *) machineName {
    struct utsname systemInfo;
    uname(&systemInfo);
    return [NSString stringWithCString:systemInfo.machine encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if([[self machineName] isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,2"]|| [[self machineName] isEqualToString:@"iPhone8,1"]) {
        [self addEventsFor3DTouchEvents];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

## pragma MARK for Adding Action for Three D Touch Events

```
- (void) addEventsFor3DTouchEvents {
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 9.0) {
        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item1 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_1 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_1] userInfo:nil];

        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item2 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_2 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_2] userInfo:nil];

        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item3 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_3 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_3] userInfo:nil];

        UIApplicationShortcutItem *item4 = [[UIApplicationShortcutItem alloc] initWithType:@"dynamic1" localizedTitle:TITLE_NAME_4 localizedSubtitle:@"" icon:[UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:TITLE_IMAGE_NAME_4] userInfo:nil];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setShortcutItems: @[ item1, item2, item3, item4 ]];
    }
}


#pragma mark - 3DTouch Delegate Methods

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performActionForShortcutItem:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)shortcutItem completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL))completionHandler {
    [self moveThrough3DTouch:shortcutItem];
}

#pragma MARK for Handling Action for Three D Touch Events

- (void)moveThrough3DTouch:(UIApplicationShortcutItem *)temp {

    if ([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_1])  {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:0];
    } else if([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_2]) {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    } else if([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_3]) {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
    } else if([temp.localizedTitle isEqualToString:TITLE_NAME_4]) {

            [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:3];
    }
}
```

**I am using Tab Bar controller in my app, If want to move in view controlled

```
- (void) moveToControllerScene {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard              = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:STORY_BOARD_IDENTIFIER bundle:nil];
        YOUR_CONTROLLER_OBJECT *obj           = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_CONTROLLER_OBJECT"];
        [navController pushViewController:obj animated:YES];
}
```